# ADODB Recordset cannot get whole multivalued field from Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, sharepoint

I have a problem with one project in my work. I have a database on Sharepoint. It's hooked into .accdb file (Access 2007/2010). So far, I used ADODB Connection with standard ConnectionString (only Provider - ACEDB 12.0).

When I try to get data from one of multivalued field from database the recordset is empty for this column. Example:

I have to get few columns: ID, Location, Name, People (MVF), Trainers (MVF).

When single record in People column has MORE than 3-4 values - the recordset for this column is empty. If there's less than 3-4 values i'm getting semicolon-separated values (Even a LEFT JOIN statement to get the source data of MVF doesn't make any difference)

I'm working on Excel - the End-user uses ONLY Excel.

When I watch a Recordset - it has empty values when the people's values should be placed - Basing on this I think the problem is caused by type of connection or something. I've tried also DAO connection - no positive results.

I've also tried to make a temporary database in .accdb file only to execute SQL (INSERT INTO tmpDB SELECT People FROM inputDB; -it's a pseudo-code, the syntax is good) And then I get "Cannot execute INSERT INTO for multivalued field".

I know, that the MVF is not recommended to use, but it's a SharePoint DB, and my role is only to get data from db to Excel.

**Update**

I tried to use the ODBC driver ...

```
objConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" & myconn & ";Uid=Admin;Pwd=;"
```

... instead of the OLEDB provider ...

```
objConn.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
objConn.Open myconn
```

... but now the MVF are always empty.

Comment: Have you tried using the Access ODBC driver instead of the OLEDB driver to see if that works any better?

Comment: It could help. I will check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem. Here's what i've done. The code could have syntax errors. I post here code written from my memory - it's not copy of my working code.

**The main and the most important thing is the type of connection.** After reserch i found that Microsoft recommends using ADO connection. As I posted earlier, the DAO requires additional looping through recordset and it could be a problem and using DAO with Connection string doesn't look better than ADO.

**The best and the only way to get data from MVFs is DAO, but the connection MUST be obtained by "OpenDatabase" method** - in this case there's no problems with MVFs with big number of values.

```
Sub ImportMVFs()

 Dim dbs As DAO.Database
 Dim rsRecord As DAO.Recordset
 Dim rsChild As DAO.Recordset
 Dim strSQL As String
 Set dbs = "Path to database - works with .accdb too"
 Set db = ws.OpenDatabase(dbs) 'This type of connection is a best way to import from MVF.

 strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblToImport;"
 Set rsRecord = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
 Debug.Print rsRecord.Field("Column1").Value
 Debug.Print rsRecord.Field("Column2").Value

 Do Until rsRecord.EOF

      Set rsChild = rsRecord.Field("MultiValuedFieldColumn") 

      Do Until rsChild.EOF
        Debug.Print rsChild.Field(0).Value 'We have to iterate through all mvfs
        'Here it's possible to make a temporary table in Access to reorganize MVFs into simple records
        'For example: Using SQLQuery as SQL string with Execute method.

        db.Execute SQLQuery
        rsChild.MoveNext
      Loop

      rsRecord.MoveNext

 Loop

 rsRecord.Close


 Set rsRecord = Nothing
 Set dbs = Nothing

End Sub
```